# Canonical URL issue for www.takemyview.co.in

Tags: htaccess, html5

My [shares and stock market](http://www.takemyview.co.in/) analysis an advisory website has canonical URL problems. My web server is not able to resolve this issue for now using htaccess or any other means and all my SEO efforts are getting wasted. Perhaps I am not so sure but this is one issue which is there since launch of my website at least since last three years. So I just want to sort this out to make sure at least conical URL issue is not hampering my traffic flow. I tried html meta code
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.takemyview.co.in/">` in index file but since this is the same URL which is having conical issue it getting refreshed on every reload and hence is not a good solution. If the browser stop after one refresh or if the browser get redirection only if user get to my website using http://takemyview.co.in or takemyview.co.in or takemyview.co.in/index.html to unique URL

Please give me immediate solution on this be kind

Comment: The site seems okay to me, what canonical url problem are you experiencing? What is the issue you are trying to fix? also the meta code you posted appears to have broken, can you edit?

Comment: Thanks for replying I found my site getting indexed separately for URL one starting with www and other without www which is concerning factor my web hosting support require htacceess as my coding is in plain html and not in php and that two users has to provide the required code now I have provided them two codes which failed to provide results I requested them to fix this error but they responded saying that they can't generate code for client

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.takemyview\.co.in [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.takemyview..co.in/$1 [R=301,L] will this be ok?

Comment: Now the issue is fixed I think by back end team of Yahoo! small business Thanks to them

Answer (score 1):

If your webserver is apache, you can use the technique from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059920/removing-index-html-from-url-and-adding-www-with-one-single-301-redirect

> In order to remove `index.html` or `index.htm` from URLs I use the following in my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.html?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html?$ "/$1" [NC,R=301,NE,L]
```

If your webserver is ngnix, you can try the solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675743/nginx-rewrite-rule-to-remove-index-html-from-the-request-uri

If you webserver is IIS, try the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057639/iis7-url-rewrite-rule-to-perform-a-301-redirect-from-html-files-to-php-files

---

Alternately, you can add a rel canonical meta tag to the `<head>` of your `index.html` file:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://takemyview.co.in/"/>
```

which will allow Google to crawl both versions, but tell it to index *only* the version without the index.html.